# onFocus interferes with onClick

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to display an autocomplete list with a function call, when onFocus event is triggered on that input field and call another function when the list item is clicked
[image]

But when I try to click the list item, the input field loses focus, the list closes and the list item onClick event is not triggered.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you tried debugging your JavaScript? That's more likely the cause, not the CSS.

Comment: Yes, I've tried to console.log something onClick, and it works, but only when the <div className = "autocomplete"> is changed to <div>

Comment: try to add to your `onClick` handler `event.preventDefault();` at the beginning

Comment: thank you, but it didn't work

Comment: I don't understand how does removing the class from element attributes makes it work.

Comment: need to see code to know whats going on. can you give a jsfiddle showing the error?

Comment: I added the code

Comment: I updated the question and made it more clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I remove focus from input text the autocomplete list was hidden and I was unable to get the clicked list item. I used **OnMouseDown** instead of **OnClick**, because OnMouseDown is fired before OnBlur and this gets the list item and only then removes the focus.